# How does one link to other defined entities using their id?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

When writing XML files I will occasionally need to reference another entity, such as a group, a category, or an action.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different methods to do this, and which one you use depends on where you are in the record:

- in the `type="xml"` or `type="html"` portions (such as `tree` and `form` views)
- everywhere else

Inside the `type=["xml" | "html"]` portions you need to use %-interpolation:

```
<button string="..." name="%(fnx_pd.action_add_cleaning_order)d" type="action" />

<field name="item_id" domain="[('categ_id','=',%(fnx_pd.pd_cleaning)d)]" />
```

The thing you are linking to needs to be inside a `%()d` or `%()s` construct: `%(module.id_name)d`.

If not inside an `xml` or `html` segment, then you can use the OpenERP-provided `ref()` function to get the id:

```
<field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,' + str(ref('action_release'))"/>

<field name="context" eval="{'default_pos_categ_id': ref('point_of_sale.categ_others')}"/>
```

In both of the above methods, OpenERP will look up the actual value associated with the id given and substitute it into the record.